# Como crear una función constructora para mostrar un año en formato fecha UTC

Tags: javascript, date

necesito crear una función constructora que recibiendo tres parámetros string (name, familyN, dateOfBirth) los objetos retornados contengan dos propiedades y una función.
Esta función al ser llamada debe retornar un número que represente el año de nacimiento en formato UTC.

Lo que yo he creado es esto:

```
function Person(name, familyN, dateOfBirth) {
        this.name = name + " " + familyN;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.getYearOfBirth = function(dateOfBirth){
            let data = Date.parse(dateOfBirth);
            data = Date.UTC(data);
    
            return data;
        }
    }

const lewis = new DriverClass('John', 'Hamill', '1989-02-09');
```

Pero no sé si está del todo correcto la creación de esta función constructora, y no sé como extraer el año en formato UTC. He añadido primero Date.parse porque si escribo directamente Date.UTC me indica 'NaN', lo paso a parse, lo compruebo con typeof y me indica que es un número, luego le indico Date.UTC y me retorna NaN igualmente.

¿Alguien podría decirme si está bien planteada la función constructora y como puedo sacar el año en formato UTC?

La solución que ha han especificado en sus respuestas puede servir, utilizando Class, pero necesito saber como resolverlo utilizando Función constructora, con prototipos. Alguien puede ayudarme? Lo que he intentado es esto:

```
function Person(name, familyN, dateOfBirth) {
        this.name = name + " " + familyN;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.getYearOfBirth = function(dateOfBirth){
            let data = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateOfBirth));
            return data.getUTCFullYear();
   
        }
    }
```

Sería el equivalente como función constructora a la resolución anterior Class?

Comment: Qué quieres decir con el año en formato UTC? El año va a seguir siendo el mismo. UTC es la franja horaria, no es un formato de fecha.

Comment: Entiendo que el año en formato UTC sería algo así: 
              getYearOfBirth(){
  let data = this._dateOfBirth.split('-');
  data = parseInt(data[0]);
  data = Date.UTC(data);
  
  return data;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar las [clases de JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Declaras la clase con `class NombreClase`, y dentro metes las propiedades y métodos que quieras.

Un nombre de método reservado es `constructor`, que es el constructor que buscas. Luego puedes añadir los métodos que quieras.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, familyN, dateOfBirth) {
    this.name = name + " " + familyN;
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
  }
  
  getYearOfBirth() {
    let data = new Date(Date.parse(this.dateOfBirth));
    
    return data.getUTCFullYear();
  }
}

const lewis = new Person('John', 'Hamill', '1989-02-09');
console.log(lewis.name);
console.log(lewis.dateOfBirth);
console.log(lewis.getYearOfBirth());
```

Comment: De acuerdo podría servir esta solución utilizando class, pero como sería con una función constructora? Con el uso de prototypes.
Las propiedades serían name y dateOfBirth en este caso no? Y la funcion getYearOfBirth.